# Can FPGA Stratix 3 memory handle large amount of data?

Tags: memory, size, vhdl, fpga, intel-fpga

I need to allocate an array in FPGA of 20 elements, each of size 323 bits, but  don't know if my fpga memory can handle this size.

I am using an FPGA Stratix 3. I hav tried looking up on the intel website : https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/programmable/products/boards_and_kits/dev-kits/altera/kit-siii-host.html, but i couldn't understand exactly which part described the memory size.

I might have 2 ways to do it : either allocate an array of 20 elements of 323 (= 17*19) bits, or a matrix of 20*19 elements of 17 bits each (which means 20*19 variables). But i don't know which way is better.
Would you have any recommendations ?

Comment: The part has plenty enough of memory inside it, and the board has even more memory available (DDR). But how to organize it depends mostly on what you plan to do with the data (parallel accesses, for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read that page you will find that the development board use the "Stratix III EP3SL150F1152" device.

Next you have to find the information for that device. I often use digikey's website for that, their website is very good for this sort of things.
Next you have to find the information for that device, which I admit is a bit difficult as the first four links I used where either too details (timing) or to broad (Family handbook).

The "Family overview" is the one you need and that has a table:

[image]

From that you can see that the EP3SL150 device has ~6.390 Kbits of memory. 
You need 20x323=6460 bits so your circuit will fit nearly a thousand times. (Well... at least as far as the memory goes. I don't know how much logic you need around the memory).